# Connect Microsoft SharePoint to Linux server

Tags: linux, sharepoint

I am new to sharepoint and I created a web page in SharePoint. I want to make connectivity to this page with linux server. So that we can run some commnads from sharepoint (send that commnad to linux server and execute from there) and we can read from Linux server into SharePoint page.

Is it very complex? or can we write small script where we can pass the server name and userid/ password to connect Linux server. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much SharePoint specificity in this question, I think.

The button on your SharePoint page may perform one of the following client-side actions:

1. Add or set SRC attribute of an IFRAME on the page to display a resource from the Linux server to the user
2. Send an asynchronous AJAX request to a resource on the Linux server and process the result.

Depending on your needs, you could also implement some server-side communication with the Linux server, but that should be unnecessary in most scenarios.